# Configuring Tests in subfolders using Google Test and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

This should be a fairly simple question, but given the black arts of project structuring using cmake, it will help quite a bit of people struggling with this.

I'm trying to get my codebase a little bit more organized. For this, I'm creating subfolders that contain the test suites according to their domain.

Google test itself is already compiling and running, the only thing is that with this restructure, Google Test can't find any of the Test Cases I have.

Here is my structure:

```
tests\
     |
     \domain1\
             |CMakeLists.txt
             |domain1_test.cpp
             |domain1_test.hpp
             |[.. more tests ...]
     \domain2\
             |CMakeLists.txt
             |domain2_test.cpp
             |domain2_test.hpp
             |[.. more tests ...]
     |main.cpp
     |CMakeLists.txt
```

As you can see, I have two folders where tests live.

The `CMakeLists.txt` files in those are as follows:

```
SET(DOMAIN1_TEST_SRC
        domain1_test.cpp
        domain1_test.hpp)

ADD_LIBRARY(domain1testlib STATIC ${DOMAIN1_TEST_SRC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(domain1testlib
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        domain_lib
        gtest
        )

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(domain1testlib
        INTERFACE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the main tests directory is:

```
add_subdirectory(domain1)
add_subdirectory(domain2)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_domain_tests main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_domain_tests
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        domain1testlib
        domain2testlib
        comptestlib
        gtest
        )

add_test(MyTestSuite my_domain_tests)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Running tests just says that No tests were found.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Adding my main.cpp

It's really nothing special, just the boilerplate main.cpp file.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: A few things to check. What's in your `main.cpp`? Do you need it or can you link against `gtest_main` instead of `gtest`, allowing gtest itself to work out what tests are available to run? Does your top level `CMakeLists.txt` have `enable_testing()` called somewhere?

Comment: I added the `main.cpp` file I'm using.Yes, my top level CMakeLists.txt has the `enable_testing()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that no symbols from your `domain*testlib`s are referenced from your executable sources, i.e. `main.cpp`.

The `TEST` and `TEST_F` macros in Google Test automatically register the test cases with the test runner. So your test source files are the ones that actually include references to symbols in the gtest library and not the other way around. Thus, the linker will not include any of your actual test cases.

You should include the `domain*_test.cpp` and `domain*_test.hpp`files as part of your executable sources instead of creating libraries with them. You can do that directly referencing the files or using a variable defined in each `CMakeLists.txt` with the list of sources.

Comment: Yeah, this fixes the issue. So, basically you have to reference everything in the main CMakeLists.txt. I thought by using libraries I would save compile time as the project grows by just compiling the things I want to test.

Comment: @HectorVillarreal: well, `make` already takes care of compiling only new/modified sources, and linkage must be done again even if you only have one source file compiled. So you wouldn't save much compilation time, indeed its (just a bit) faster if you don't have libraries since you don't spend time creating and expanding archives.

Answer (score -1):

> What am I doing wrong?
>
> Running tests just says that No tests were found.

to make available for "make test" and to work ctest inside build dir you need

```
  ENABLE_TESTING()# Force "make test" to works
```

before add_test in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: The problem is not that `make test` doesn't run the test executable. The OP says he runs the tests and the executable reports that there are no test found. Plus, he is not using `CTest`, but `gtest`.